# how to add filters on video using GPUImage in Android?

Tags: android, video, filter

I have used GPUImage filters to filter an image ....Is there any way to filter a video file using GPUImage filter in android. If any other way suggest me please.I have seen simple video file filter in iOS but some classes required to perform the same step have not yet been written.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen this? https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Decode video frame into bitmap
2. Fitler decoded bitmap using GPUImage
3. Encode filtered bitmap into output video file